# how read values from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Question for me is i want to get a data from sqlite database for specific Id and if the That ID is Not Exists in the database i need to show a message saying Invalid ID , Problem is in my code is it works when the Id matches .but when database does not have the value which i search for i get crashed the app. im a newbie to programming i know this is something wrong in my logic where i put this.please help.tried several times

```
package com.my.myapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DBSqliteAddSTDinfo {

public static final String  KEY_STDNO = "S_no";
public static final String  KEY_NAME = "First_Name";
public static final String  KEY_AGE = "Age";


private static final String DBNAME = "second"; 
private static final String TBLNAME  = "details";
private static final int DBversion = 1;

private DbHelper OurHelper;
private final Context OurContext;
private SQLiteDatabase OurDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBversion);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TBLNAME + " (" +
                KEY_STDNO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBLNAME );
       onCreate(db);

    }



}

  public DBSqliteAddSTDinfo(Context c){

      OurContext = c;

  }

  public DBSqliteAddSTDinfo open()throws SQLException{

      OurHelper = new DbHelper(OurContext);
      OurDatabase = OurHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      return this;


  }

  public void close(){
      if (OurDatabase != null){
          OurDatabase.close(); 
            OurHelper.close();
      }

  } 

/*EditText editID,editFname,editLname,editDOB,editSname,editGrade_Year,editClass;
Button Submit;
SQLiteDatabase db;*/

public long creatEntry(String Id, String Name, String Age) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_STDNO, Id);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, Name);
    cv.put(KEY_AGE, Age);


    return OurDatabase.insert(TBLNAME, null, cv);

}

public String getName(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_STDNO, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE};
    Cursor c = OurDatabase.query(TBLNAME, columns, KEY_STDNO + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(1);
        return name;
    }

    return null;
}

public String getAge(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_STDNO, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE};
    Cursor c = OurDatabase.query(TBLNAME, columns, KEY_STDNO + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String age = c.getString(2);
        return age;
    }


    return null;
}

public void updateEntry(long lRow, String sname, String sage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues update = new ContentValues();

    update.put(KEY_NAME, sname);
    update.put(KEY_AGE, sage);
    OurDatabase.update(TBLNAME, update, KEY_STDNO + "=" + lRow, null);
}

public void deleteEntry(long lRowdel) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    OurDatabase.delete(TBLNAME, KEY_STDNO + "=" + lRowdel, null);

}

public String getNo(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_STDNO, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE};
    Cursor c = OurDatabase.query(TBLNAME, columns, KEY_STDNO + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String sno = c.getString(0);
        return sno;
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

```
package com.my.myapp;



import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.my.myapp.DBSqliteAddSTDinfo;

public class ViewData extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText id,name,age,ID;
Button ViewData,Update;


@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void onClick(View v){

     id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ViewId);
     name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ViewName);
     age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ViewAge);
     ID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextID);


     ViewData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewData); 




     DBSqliteAddSTDinfo hon = new DBSqliteAddSTDinfo(this);
     hon.open();


     if(id.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
        {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(ViewData.this);
                d.setTitle("ID Can Not Be Empty");
                TextView tv = new TextView(ViewData.this);
                tv.setText("Unsuccessful ! ");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();

            return;
        }

     String s = id.getText().toString();
     long l = Long.parseLong(s);
     String returnedName = hon.getName(l);
     String returnedAge  = hon.getAge(l);
     String returnedSno = hon.getNo(l);

     //String NewSno = Long.toString(l);

     if(returnedSno.equals(s)){

         name.setText(returnedName);
         age.setText(returnedAge);
         ID.setText(returnedSno);        

            /*Dialog d = new Dialog(ViewData.this);
            d.setTitle("Invalied ID");
            TextView tv = new TextView(ViewData.this);
            tv.setText("Unsuccessful ! ");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();*/

        //return;

     }
    if(hon.getNo(l)== null && hon.getName(l)== null && hon.getAge(l)== null ){


            Dialog d = new Dialog(ViewData.this);
            d.setTitle("Invalied ID");
            TextView tv = new TextView(ViewData.this);
            tv.setText("Unsuccessful ! ");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();

        //return; 
        /*name.setText(returnedName);
         age.setText(returnedAge);
         ID.setText(returnedSno);   */

     }
     hon.close();
    }





private void clearText() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    id.setText("");
    name.setText("");
    age.setText("");
}

private void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    {
        Builder builder=new Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }

}

public void onClickUpdate(View v){

    String sname = name.getText().toString();
    String sage = age.getText().toString();     
    String sRow = id.getText().toString();
    long lRow = Long.parseLong(sRow);

    DBSqliteAddSTDinfo upd = new DBSqliteAddSTDinfo(this);
    upd.open();
    upd.updateEntry(lRow, sname, sage);
    upd.close();


}

public void onClickDelete(View v){

    String sRowdel = id.getText().toString();
    long lRowdel = Long.parseLong(sRowdel);

    DBSqliteAddSTDinfo del = new DBSqliteAddSTDinfo(this);
    del.open();
    del.deleteEntry(lRowdel);
    del.close();




}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_data);

     /*id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ViewId);
     name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ViewName);
     age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ViewAge);

     ViewData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewData); 
     String s = id.getText().toString();
     long l = Long.parseLong(s);
     DBSqliteAddSTDinfo hon = new DBSqliteAddSTDinfo(this);
     hon.open();
     String returnedName = hon.getName(l);
     String returnedAge  = hon.getAge(l);

     name.setText(returnedName);
     age.setText(returnedAge);

     hon.close(); */













}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_data, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: c.moveToFirst() returns what you need ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if(c != null){
    c.moveToFirst();
```

to

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
```

The cursor won't be null and you need to check the return value of `moveToFirst()` to see whether the cursor contains any rows before accessing its data with `getString()` and such.